# Apache require ip range

Tags: apache2, ip

Is is possible to give a defined range with `require ip`?

I have tried online calculators with masks and CIDR but cannot seem to find the correct answer.

I would like for example to set the range at `192.168.0.20` to `192.168.0.189` (to allow acces to local static IP range but deny local DHCP range), is this possible?

Comment: 192.168.0.X are not valid IP addresses. Zero is use to say any IP in this range, so can only be followed by zeros. You could have 192.168.1.20 to 192.168.1.189 or 192.168.1.0 for example to define ranges

Comment: I'm even more confused now.  I have several machines with static ip address, set between this range, 192.168.0.20, 192.168.0.21, 192.168.0.43, etc.  Everything in terms of ip addresses, hosts, etc seems to work OK, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Reading [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require), I did not find a way to give ip range to `require ip` directive, as you need.

So, you should list every ip address one per `require ip` directive.

Another possibility is to use [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) to define a variable if `Remote_Addr` matches you ip range:

```
 SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^192\.168\.0\.([2-9][0-9])$|^192\.168\.0\.1([0-8][0-9])$" allowIp
 Require env allowIp
```

I didn't test it and regex can be improved for sure, but I think that this can give you a direction.